# why linked list is stacked in recursive order?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was going through an article, and it was said that, A linked list can be defined by --
**A List is either Empty or an Element followed by a List.**

```
enum List<T> {
    x(T, Box<List<T>>),
    Nil,
}
```

And i saw an expression -- `List a = Empty | Elem a (List a)`
Which was expanded by -- **`x(1, Box(x(2, Box(Nil))))`**

I want to know why linked list is stored in a recursive order??like, **a list within a list within a list and like so on**??

Comment: How else would you store it?

Comment: in a plain list?

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a linked list, would it?

Comment: Well that was my question, why i need to nest the lists.and what is the benefit of nesting if i want is pointing to next element?

Comment: Without wanting to spark debate, linked lists are a poor data structure for most applications, but they are practical for teaching concepts related to how they work! For your use, I think practically the key is that the "next" element is a _reference_, not the value itself, allowing addition of arbitrarily-many nodes without needing to know the length or information about the size of objects in the list.

Comment: This is basically a question about definitions. There are plenty of ways to organize data. This particular way is called a "linked list". You are welcome to organize your data in some other way. In which case it would something other than a linked list. (It's like asking, "Why does a bicycle have to have two wheels?"  If it had three wheels, it it wouldn't be called a "bicycle"; it would be called a "tricycle".)

Comment: well, nice try.